# Downloading a File in Swift without caching it

Tags: ios, caching, swift, download

I am using NSURLSession to download a file from a specific url. I have come to the conclusion after several tests that the app itself caches the file, so when I try to download it again the app overrides my instructions and shows me the cached file. Is there a way to say to the program not to cache files? I have searched and haven't found anything... :(

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Look at NSURLRequest cachepolicy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you inititalize the `NSURLRequest` you'll use with the Download Task, make sure to pass `NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData`as the value for the `cachePolicy` argument.